# WordPress Pretty Permalinks

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, permalinks

Pretty permalinks are no longer working, I've tried all the obvious things;

- Re-save permalinks
- Delete and regenerate HTAccess
- Disable all plugins
- Restarted Apache
- Cleared browser cache (although this issue happens for everyone)
- Checked the tables via PHPMyAdmin
- Enabled WP debugging, nothing is showing

The pages are there and work fine if using plain links.

This is the only site that has the issue, other sites running on the same dev server are fine.

The issue is only apparent in recent versions of the database, so I do have a working version that could be used for debugging, but I'm unsure what to be looking for.

Any help would be greatly received!

Comment: do you have a backup to try restoring and see if the issue exist?

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by a CPT for which rewrites did work before.

Disable the CPT rewrite option and now things work.